# Avoid SSH AgentForwarding of incompatible keys

Tags: ssh-keys, rhel7, ssh-agent

Good morning,
I have one ed25519-sk key (using a hardware token), which I need only on my personal machine for some high security servers (all Debian). This key type is supported by OpenSSH 8.3+. We still have two machines running RHEL 7 which offers OpenSSH 7.2.

There is now an implementation glitch in the agent forwarding. It seems to send all the keys in the `~/.ssh/` dir as a byte stream. It does not check whether the keys are needed or compatible on the server side.

**If there is only one incompatible key, there are no keys transferred at all.** Not even the compatible ones.

```
server $ ssh-add -l
error fetching identities for protocol 1: agent refused operation
error fetching identities for protocol 2: invalid format
The agent has no identities.
```

To be clear, I don't need the ed25519-sk key on the server but I need ForwardAgent to be enabled here because we're using this to access Git repos.

A workaround is to move the ed25529-sk key out of the `~/.ssh/` directory.

Anybody has an idea how to achive both of the following?

- Keep the ed25529-sk key on my local machine in the `~/.ssh` dir
- Forward all other|compatible keys to the server

Comment: Have you tried adding a *destination constraint* when adding that key to your agent? Lack of constraint extension should error out in a different place than unexpected key format.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand how `ForwardAgent` works.

When you enable agent forwarding via SSH it actually forwards your local `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` UNIX socket to the remote machine through the secure tunnel.
This means that `ssh-add -l` on the remote machine talks to the same `ssh-agent` process as the one your local `ssh-add -l` does. As such it cannot filter anything because it's just a "dumb" `RemoteForward` with a few extras (creating the remote directory to place the socket in and setting the appropriate environment variable).

You either need to spawn a separate `ssh-agent` to be forwarded or authenticate differently to your git repositories.

Comment: The entire point of the `session-bind@openssh.com` extension was to make the agent less dumb so it *can* filter on different connections.

Comment: @anx, that extension landed in OpenSSH 8.9 which Debian stable does not have.

Comment: The extension makes the agent less dumb, but it doesn't look like it will solve this particular problem.  See https://www.openssh.com/agent-restrict.html for the complete story.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past this problem by using the command

```
ssh-agent ssh -A myhost
```

When used this way, a new SSH agent is started, then only the key for accessing myhost was added to the agent, which was the one I needed on my CentOS 7 machine.